# Aggregate metrics in child workers for pm2 cluster mode

Tags: node.js, performance, metrics, pm2

I use PM2 to start my application in cluster mode. But as I know, in that case PM2 does not allow to run my code in master process, but I need to collect metrics (CPU usage, memory etc.).

Is it possible to aggregate metrics or get metrics for whole app (PM2 cluster mode) in child workers and, for example, show these metrics on `/metrics` route?

Unfortunately, I cannot to find any open source libs for that :(

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found `pm2 web + pmx`. It is solved my problem.

Comment: How did you achieve that? Could you show some samples or explain a bit more? Thanks.

Comment: @EricSonaron, start `pm2 web` and navigate to http://localhost:9615/. You'll see a lot of metrics for apps which you launched using pm2. 

pmx is deprecated, use https://github.com/keymetrics/pm2-io-apm.

after that, you can create your own metrics collector which will parse http://localhost:9615/ and send metrics to storage.